# Use the native mobile Facebook application to request credentials

Tags: iphone, android, facebook

I'm using Facebook connect for request credentials to the user's information.
I'm doing it from the web browser.
If the user is using a mobile (Android/Iphone) device, all the authorization process goes inside the browser.

Is it possible to raise the Facebook application (if it's already installed) and pass all the authorization process there? instead of keep using the browser (to improve the user experience).

I can detect if the user is coming from a mobile device (by his user-agent for example), maybe I can add some special url schema to raise the Facebook application?

Thanks,
Itay.

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to do this (using the auth flow via the native app from a mobile browser) but were you aware that if the user is logged in to Facebook in their mobile browser that when you pop the [OAuth dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) they will not have to enter their Facebook credentials? Their logged in state will be auto-detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iPhone: try to see with openURL function. See [this article](http://mobileorchard.com/opening-the-facebook-app-to-your-facebook-fan-page/) for more information to launch Facebook app

Comment: Thanks, any idea for Android?